# XMLHttpRequest return 403 on new server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use a library (orakupload) to upload photos. This makes a query through XMLHttpRequest to a php file from the same library, which save the image.
On the old server it works perfectly, but we have changed the server and it has stopped working.
Calling the php file I get a 403 Forbidden. This file is in exactly the same folder as the Js that calls it (logically, also the same server).
I have searched and tried everything, but I can't get it to not return the error, let's see if you can help me.

The XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", settings.orakuploader_path+"orakuploader.php?filename="+encodeURIComponent(file.name)+"&path="+settings.orakuploader_path+"&resize_to="+settings.orakuploader_resize_to+"&thumbnail_size="+settings.orakuploader_thumbnail_size+"&main_path="+settings.orakuploader_main_path+"&thumbnail_path="+settings.orakuploader_thumbnail_path+"&watermark="+settings.orakuploader_watermark+"&orakuploader_crop_to_width="+settings.orakuploader_crop_to_width+"&orakuploader_crop_to_height="+settings.orakuploader_crop_to_height+"&orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_width="+settings.orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_width+"&orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_height="+settings.orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_height, true);
        xhr.send(file);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
...
```

If I open the path that creates, and open directly in chrome, it executes the php file without problem.

So I think it must not be the htaccess problem.
I thought that for some reason it could be a CORS problem, but I add the headers to the php file and it continues with the problem:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Finally, I leave here the information of the headers in the query, in case it can be of help:

```
General
Request URL: https://www.XXXXXX.com/intranet/orakuploader/orakuploader.php?filename=aaaa.png&path=/intranet/orakuploader/&resize_to=0&thumbnail_size=0&main_path=/intranet/files&thumbnail_path=/intranet/files/tn&watermark=&orakuploader_crop_to_width=1920&orakuploader_crop_to_height=1420&orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_width=200&orakuploader_crop_thumb_to_height=200
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 52.121.xx.xx:xxx
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin


Response Header
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 318
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Wed, 21 Jul 2021 12:33:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=53
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN


Request Header
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es,ca;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 200316
Content-Type: image/png
Cookie: xxxxxxx
Host: www.XXXXXX.com
Origin: https://www.XXXXXX.com
Referer: https://www.XXXXXX.com/intranet/prop/1193
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
```

**EDIT**

If I disconnect the ssl certificate, it does not save the image, but I do not receive the 403 error, could the cause be here?

Comment: Fiddling with any CORS settings is pointless here (you are making the request to the _same_ origin, according to what you said), and it can’t be an HTTPS issue either (if it was, then the client and server would break the whole thing off, before they even start talking HTTP with each other, so that you could not even get a 403.) What do the log files on the server have to say?

Comment: I know it couldn't be a CORS problem, but I didn't know what else to try. The SSL part commented on it because maybe it helped to solve the problem. It seems to be a server configuration, since in the previous one it works.

Comment: I only can access to read the php log file. And don't have any line for this problem. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, I leave it here in case it helps someone:

Finish looking for the apache "mod_security" module. And I found that one of rules was blocking the request.